# Can I export an Access form to Excel with the same exact formatting?

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I have a continuous access form where all controls are snapped into the grid. When I try the Excel export tool in the ribbon, it exports it as a traditional table, but I want to keep the formatting I have on the form (number of columns/rows per record, location of controls, colors, etc.). Is this possible with VBA? I don't mind if I even have to re-create the format in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the command:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, Me.Name, acFormatXLSX, ..etc.
```

It seems to preserve some formatting.